after "minipage" command, words cannot change line auto but extend the page layout
I meet some issue after I use minipage. My article is a single column. To reduce the number of pages, I used minipage to combine the tables and related images of two experiments into one page (Of course, I reduced the font size of the table). Now there is still space at the bottom where I want to edit the text, but the text does not wrap automatically but goes beyond the page boundary. I want to write as much text as possible on the page while the table is always at the top. Because I have six experiments, I plan to present the results on three pages, while editing the text normally at the bottom of each page. The below is code and output image. Looking forward to and thank you for your discussion!
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}
%\usepackage{truetype}% what's this?
%\usepackage{latexsym}% obsolete
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
%文章如果不涉及子图，以下代码可以删除，本文因需要一起示例排版，就保留了
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[]{caption2} %新增调用的宏包
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.} %重定义编号前缀词
\renewcommand{\captionlabeldelim}{.~} %重定义分隔符
 %\roman是罗马数字编号，\alph是默认的字母编号，\arabic是阿拉伯数字编号，可按需替换下一行的相应位置
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\roman{subfigure})}%此外，还可设置图编号显示格式，加括号或者不加括号
\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@thesubfigure}{\thesubfigure \space}%子图编号与名称的间隔设置
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{} \makeatother
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{pifont,color,multicol}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,ragged2e}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
%\usepackage{times}% deprecated
%\usepackage{mwe}% useless
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{graphics}% not needed
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}  % loads »blindtext« and »graphicx«
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{inputenc}% useless
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{color}% useless with xcolor
\usepackage{,soul}
%\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}% use tcolorbox
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}% not along with subfig
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal Name}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\biboptions{numbers,sort&compress}

%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}% why?

%\newcounter{myfn}[page]% what for?

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}

% DON'T CHANGE THE PAGINATION PARAMETERS!
%\topmargin -0,75in \textheight 9,5 in
%\oddsidemargin -0.1in \textwidth 6.5in
%\evensidemargin -0.5in \footskip .5in

%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}% what for?

%\def\Proof.{{\bf{Proof. }}}
%\def\End{\hspace{1cm} $\Box$\\}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}% what for?

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% THE FOLLOWING ARE WRONG!
%\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
%\newfont{\bb}{msbm10 scaled\magstep1}
%\newcommand{\bN}{\mbox{\bb N}}
%\newcommand{\bZ}{\mbox{\bb Z}}
%\newcommand{\bQ}{\mbox{\bb Q}}
%\newcommand{\bR}{\mbox{\bb R}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\bQ}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth} 
\centering 
\begin{table}[H]
\footnotesize
\centering \caption{Experiment 1}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{$h$} & \multirow{2}{*}{METHOD} & $B=100$ &  &  \\
&  & {MGTE} & {NFE} & {Time(s)}\\
\midrule
\multirow{5}{*}
{0.025}&X&4.084364(-16)&12000&0.519\\
&XX&1.802952(-13)&12000&0.539\\
&XXX&1.562715(-5)&12000&0.587\\
&XXXX&5.960929(-13)&24000&0.719\\
&XXXXX&1.912294(-4)&32000&0.632\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
\multirow{5}{*}
{0.020}&X&1.144546(-17)&15000&0.595\\
&XX&1.934776(-14)&15000&0.632\\
&XXX&5.115801(-6)&15000&0.749\\
&XXXX&1.039706(-13)&30000&0.856\\
&XXXXX&6.171445(-5)&40000&0.754\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
\multirow{5}{*}
{0.015}&X&1.142831(-19)&20000&0.756\\
&XX&1.089515(-15)&20000&0.932\\
&XXX&1.214425(-6)&20000&0.938\\
&XXXX&1.140415(-14)&40000&1.145\\
&XXXXX&1.450237(-5)&53333&1.014\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
\multirow{5}{*}
{0.010}&X&1.737694(-22)&30000&1.250\\
&XX&7.568127(-17)&30000&1.260\\
&XXX&1.599277(-7)&30000&1.309\\
&XXXX&5.498041(-16)&60000&1.769\\
&XXXXX&1.895651(-6)&80000&1.509\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
\multirow{5}{*}
{0.005}&X&2.648241(-27)&60000&2.447\\
&XX&1.847588(-20)&60000&2.601\\
&XXX&4.996194(-9)&60000&2.688\\
&XXXX&3.887940(-18)&120000&3.390\\
&XXXXX&5.894875(-8)&160000&3.072\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=5cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Numerical graph for experiment 1 with \\\hspace{\textwidth} $B = 100$ and $h = 0.025 - 0.005i (i = 0,1,2,3,4)$.}
\label{Figure test1}
\end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{minipage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth} 
\centering 
\begin{table}[H]
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption{Experiment 2}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{$h$} & \multirow{2}{*}{METHOD} & $B=100$ &  &  \\
&  & {MGTE} & {NFE} & {Time(s)}\\
\midrule
\multirow{5}{*}
{0.1}&X&4.256602(-21)&3000&0.092\\
&XX&1.213163(-16)&12000&0.089\\
&XXX&3.294553(-7)&12000&0.161\\
&XXXX&1.998695(-14)&24000&0.146\\
&XXXXX&9.584079(-2)&32000&0.195\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
\multirow{5}{*}
{0.05}&X&6.479610(-26)&6000&0.272\\
&XX&1.184842(-19)&15000&0.268\\
&XXX&1.029791(-8)&15000&0.268\\
&XXXX&1.175856(-16)&30000&0.339\\
&XXXXX&4.781334(-2)&40000&0.316\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
\multirow{5}{*}
{0.025}&X&9.881954(-31)&12000&0.514\\
&XX&1.156993(-22)&20000&0.560\\
&XXX&3.217851(-10)&20000&0.554\\
&XXXX&1.187549(-18)&40000&0.691\\
&XXXXX&2.389332(-2)&53333&0.764\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
\multirow{5}{*}
{0.0125}&X&1.507622(-35)&24000&0.961\\
&XX&1.129826(-25)&30000&1.075\\
&XXX&1.005527(-11)&30000&1.129\\
&XXXX&1.701612(-20)&60000&1.423\\
&XXXXX&1.194500(-2)&80000&1.324\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
\multirow{5}{*}
{0.00625}&X&2.300318(-40)&48000&1.871\\
&XX&1.103319(-28)&60000&2.107\\
&XXX&3.142220(-13)&60000&2.091\\
&XXXX&2.679244(-22)&120000&2.780\\
&XXXXX&5.972292(-3)&160000&2.606\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=5cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{Numerical graph for experiment 2 with \\\hspace{\textwidth} $B = 100$ and $h = 0.1/{2^i} (i = 0,1,2,3,4)$.}
\label{Figure test1}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage} \\ \\ 
\linebreak
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



why do you have comments like what's this? and obsolete in your source? if you know that, why don't you just remove the package?  you have provided no effective example of the problem because tex cannot possibly break a continuous sequence of xs regardless. your preamble will cause you problems, headaches and enormous amounts of wasted effort. to avoid this, you should clean it up.

@cfr Because I have asked questions on this website before, I copied some usepackage comments directly to overleaf. I planned to delete them when I submitted the paper. I forgot to delete them this time. I apologize if it caused you trouble. In addition, thank you for your comments. I will pay attention to the issues you mentioned.

From the code and screenshot, it appears that you're trying to force a line break using \\ \linebreak after the minipage environment. However, this isn't the most effective way to control text flow in LaTeX, especially when dealing with floats (tables and figures).
LaTeX is designed to handle float placement intelligently. Instead of forcing a break, let's instruct LaTeX to place the remaining text after the minipage environment, ensuring it flows naturally within the column and onto subsequent pages if needed.
While whatever garbage you provided was practically irrelevant, if not useless, I suggest you put more effort into your problem if you want help. Nonetheless, here's a full working example to recreate your desired output. You didn't show a sample of the problematic text that "overflows," which, in all honesty, should overflow for sure as it's considered 1 long word for LaTeX to hyphenate. In anticipation of your messy description and sample, I have decided for you to modify the geometry of the page to give you enough space to write whatever conclusion you can come up with. It should be fairly easy from this point forward to adjust to meet your unknown needs.
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}

% Include necessary packages
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For generating Lorem Ipsum text
\usepackage{geometry} % For controlling margins and page geometry

% Adjust margins to reduce wasted space
\geometry{
    top=1.5cm,
    bottom=1.5cm,
    left=1.5cm,
    right=1.5cm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]  % Enclose both minipages within a figure* environment

% Table for Experiment 1
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\scriptsize % Slightly reduce font size for tables
\captionof{table}{Experiment 1} 
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule 
$h$ & METHOD & MGTE & NFE & Time(s) \\ 
\midrule 
0.025 & X & 4.084364(-16) & 12000 & 0.519 \\
      & XX & 1.802952(-13) & 12000 & 0.539 \\
      & XXX & 1.562715(-5)  & 12000 & 0.587 \\
      & XXXX & 5.960929(-13) & 24000 & 0.719 \\
      & XXXXX & 1.912294(-4) & 32000 & 0.632 \\
\midrule 
0.020 & X & 1.144546(-17) & 15000 & 0.595 \\
      & XX & 1.934776(-14) & 15000 & 0.632 \\
      & XXX & 5.115801(-6)  & 15000 & 0.749 \\
      & XXXX & 1.039706(-13) & 30000 & 0.856 \\
      & XXXXX & 6.171445(-5) & 40000 & 0.754 \\
\midrule 
0.015 & X & 1.142831(-19) & 20000 & 0.756 \\
      & XX & 1.089515(-15) & 20000 & 0.932 \\
      & XXX & 1.214425(-6)  & 20000 & 0.938 \\
      & XXXX & 1.140415(-14) & 40000 & 1.145 \\
      & XXXXX & 1.450237(-5) & 53333 & 1.014 \\
\midrule 
0.010 & X & 1.737694(-22) & 30000 & 1.250 \\
      & XX & 7.568127(-17) & 30000 & 1.260 \\
      & XXX & 1.599277(-7)  & 30000 & 1.309 \\
      & XXXX & 5.498041(-16) & 60000 & 1.769 \\
      & XXXXX & 1.895651(-6) & 80000 & 1.509 \\
\midrule 
0.005 & X & 2.648241(-27) & 60000 & 2.447 \\
      & XX & 1.847588(-20) & 60000 & 2.601 \\
      & XXX & 4.996194(-9)  & 60000 & 2.688 \\
      & XXXX & 3.887940(-18) & 120000 & 3.390 \\
      & XXXXX & 5.894875(-8) & 160000 & 3.072 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.4cm} % Adjust spacing between table and image

\centering
\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=5cm]{example-image-a} 
\captionof{figure}{Numerical graph for experiment 1 with $B = 100$ and $h = 0.025 - 0.005i (i = 0,1,2,3,4)$.}
\label{Figure test1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
% Table for Experiment 2
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\scriptsize % Slightly reduce font size for tables
\captionof{table}{Experiment 2} 
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule 
$h$ & METHOD & MGTE & NFE & Time(s) \\ 
\midrule 
0.1 & X & 4.256602(-21) & 3000 & 0.092 \\
    & XX & 1.213163(-16) & 12000 & 0.089 \\
    & XXX & 3.294553(-7)  & 12000 & 0.161 \\
    & XXXX & 1.998695(-14) & 24000 & 0.146 \\
    & XXXXX & 9.584079(-2) & 32000 & 0.195 \\
\midrule 
0.05 & X & 6.479610(-26) & 6000 & 0.272 \\
     & XX & 1.184842(-19) & 15000 & 0.268 \\
     & XXX & 1.029791(-8)  & 15000 & 0.268 \\
     & XXXX & 1.175856(-16) & 30000 & 0.339 \\
     & XXXXX & 4.781334(-2) & 40000 & 0.316 \\
\midrule 
0.025 & X & 9.881954(-31) & 12000 & 0.514 \\
      & XX & 1.156993(-22) & 20000 & 0.560 \\
      & XXX & 3.217851(-10)  & 20000 & 0.554 \\
      & XXXX & 1.187549(-18) & 40000 & 0.691 \\
      & XXXXX & 2.389332(-2) & 53333 & 0.764 \\
\midrule 
0.0125 & X & 1.507622(-35) & 24000 & 0.961 \\
       & XX & 1.129826(-25) & 30000 & 1.075 \\
       & XXX & 1.005527(-11)  & 30000 & 1.129 \\
       & XXXX & 1.701612(-20) & 60000 & 1.423 \\
       & XXXXX & 1.194500(-2) & 80000 & 1.324 \\
\midrule 
0.00625 & X & 2.300318(-40) & 48000 & 1.871 \\
        & XX & 1.103319(-28) & 60000 & 2.107 \\
        & XXX & 3.142220(-13)  & 60000 & 2.091 \\
        & XXXX & 2.679244(-22) & 120000 & 2.780 \\
        & XXXXX & 5.972292(-3) & 160000 & 2.606 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.4cm} % Adjust spacing between table and image

\centering
\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=5cm]{example-image-b} 
\captionof{figure}{Numerical graph for experiment 2 with $B = 100$ and $h = 0.1/2^i (i = 0,1,2,3,4)$.}
\label{Figure test2}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure*} 

% Add the Lorem Ipsum text directly after the figure* environment
\vspace{0.3cm} % Adjust this value to reduce space and avoid text overflow
\footnotesize % Make the placeholder text slightly smaller
\lipsum[1] % Insert the first paragraph of Lorem Ipsum text

\end{document}

I hope that answers your question.
--halsten

Thanks for your valuable and detailed answer, particular added usepackage and format optimization and adjustment, thank you for your answer!

Is there any reason you can't accept this answer?

no reason. Why you say that? I really appreciate your answer!

@Aixleftmath Usually, if the OP (you) finds the answer to solve his problem, explains it, and so on, they will check the "sign under the upvote and downvote to show that the question was answered and that it is the correct one. It's not mandatory, but it's the goal, so it's not left unsolved. It also helps others with similar problems to see that there is a solution, as the indicator is a green tag. That's all.

no wonder! Thanks for your mention! I don't know it before! And I have just vote your answer!
